# 2023 Community Moderator Election Results

Tags: discussion, election

[Moderator election #3](https://music.stackexchange.com/election/3) on Music: Practice & Theory has come to a close, the votes have been tallied, and the new moderator is:

[image: Elements in Space]

They will be joining [the existing crew](https://music.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) shortly — please thank them for volunteering and share your assistance and advice with them as they learn the ropes!

Also, please join me in thanking Richard, who will be stepping down as moderator after serving in the role for the past 3 years:

[image: Richard]

For details on how the voting played out, you can download the election results [here](https://music.stackexchange.com/election/3) or [view a summary report online](https://www.opavote.com/results/6698464908935168).

Comment: This is thrilling news; I was so happy to see Elements nominate, and I'm even happier to see that they've won. It's a good day for Music.SE.

Answer (score 8):

Thanks, Richard, for three years of exceptional moderation.

Congratulations, ElementsInSpace, on stepping into big shoes I've every confidence you can fill.

The Moderator is retired. Long serve the Moderator.

Answer (score 5):

I'm sad that Richard couldn't continue his 3 yrs of sterling work - always fair - and a big thank-you to him.

I think we'll be in safe hands with ElementsInSpace (certainly hope so!!),as they have lots of experience on this site, which I'm sure they will use to our advantage.

Congratulations, EIS!